# How to find the subsequence of the largest sums in C/MIPS?

Tags: c, arrays, mips, subsequence

So the following input in an array would be something like

```
  Array: {7 2 5 -3 3 6 -4 1}
```

and the subsequence would be

```
 Subseq: : 7 2 5 -3 3 6
```

and the answer to the largest sum would be 20. So, what exactly is going on here. I am not understanding the concept of a subsequence. After reading, I thought the subsequence started at array[0] and went through to array[n] and picked the largest numbers but that does not seem to be the case because the numbers should have stopped after the number 7 then. I am confused on what exactly a subsequence is doing with this user entered array.

Comment: We are not a "explain my homework" site. Ask your tutor. It is his job to teach you and explain if you have questions.

Comment: @olaf if you could explain a concept, I could do my homework. I don't understand what is going on here because to me, the answer should be 7 because as soon as it reaches a lower number, shouldn't the code stop. I wasn't asking you to do it but thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1):

What he is really finding is a sum of a lot of values together so he can get the maximum number possible.
    Stop at 7 it just give the total o 7.

```
7 2 = 9

7 2 5 = 14

7 2 5 - 3 = 11

7 2 5 - 3 3 = 14

7 2 5 -3 3 6 = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

After the above help, the reason for my confusion was being unsure of exactly what a subsequence is doing. However, I now understand that it is taking the largest grouping of numbers and adding them together. In my example of numbers:

```
 Array: {7,2,5,-3,3,6,-4,1}
```

It takes the digits:

```
 Answer: {7,2,5,-3,3,6}              //adds to = 20
```

This is the largest sum of a continuous sequence of numbers.

Another example of a simple subsequence would be:

```
 Array: {-5 -10 5 5 -5 -10}
 Answer:{5, 5}   //it adds 5 and 5 because that is the largest continuous sequence (10)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your title answers your question: largest sum of subsequence

So you have to find elements in the array whose sum is maximum. In this case : 7+2+5-3+3+6 = 20

Comment: that kind of makes sense but how would someone go about that. Is there a specific algorithm to follow? I don't get how it would keep checking because once it reaches a negative number, I assume that the it should stop. Not sure if that comment is clear but I understand what you said